# Java excel - Comparing two strings

Tags: java, excel

I have to check the strings of two xlsx files if they are equal must return the name, but it always returns null, someone can help me?

```
try
    {
        FileInputStream fisCod = new FileInputStream(pathC);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (fisCod);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        for(int i=0; i<lastRow; i++)
        {      
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(jobCod);  

            String tmp = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().toLowerCase();

            if (tmp.equals(jobName)) //jobName is a String
            {
                return tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        fisCod.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: What is null?  `row`? `cell`? `tmp`? `jobName`? or are you saying `tmp.equals(jobName)` is always false?  Have you tried outputting the values to see any discrepancies?  What are the values of `tmp` and `jobName`?

Comment: If IF condition is not satisfied, you will always get null. just debug it or try with equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: With equalsIgnoreCase is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mismatch in the above code will cause `null` to be returned without checking subsequent row values. More than likely, this is the scenario you are describing.

Check *all* cell values *before* resorting to returning `null` when the attempted match fails.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(jobCod);

    String tmp = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().toLowerCase();

    if (tmp.equals(jobName)) {
        return tmp;
    }
}

return null; // now return null
```